# Solr returning way more values

Tags: django, solr

Using Django 2.2.7, Python 3.6.9, PySolr 3.8.1, DJANGO Haystack 2.8.1

```
haystack_conn = {}
search_engine = 'solr'
if search_engine == 'whoosh':
    haystack_conn = {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'whoosh_index'),
    }
elif search_engine == 'solr':
    haystack_conn = {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/bsd',
    }
elif search_engine == 'elastic_search':
    haystack_conn = {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'artifacts',
    }

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': haystack_conn,
}


HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 10
```

When I search for ex. ios I get 250 results. When I search ios 10 i get 500 results, although I should get less .. around 90.

Comment: it depends on how you have indexed the data....share how is the fieldtype applied to your field...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/i3iLZQBu

Comment: I am searching via artifact name. ios , then ios 11.

Comment: the field name="artifact_name"  had fieldtype="text_en" defined ...but I dont see the entire defination of text_en...like what all tokenizer it has and filter it consist of...Do you want the result of exact match?

Comment: yes exact match. for ex. if i search ios, everything that has ios ( which includes ios 11). But if I search ios 11 ( I don't want ios, but ios 11 )

Comment: strange error... no way to fix it from settings file?

Comment: at times it works on certain searches, other searches not..

Comment: This behavior depends on the `q.op` setting - if it's set to `OR` by default, the result will include documents with either `ios` or `11` or both. If you change it to `q.op=AND`, only those where both terms are present will be included.

Comment: thank you for help, I got answer. and provided it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone in future searches for this

in solrconfig.xml I added the below, this solution worked for me.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
      will be overridden by parameters in the request
    -->
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="df">text_en</str>
        <str name="q.op">AND</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the string type for your field artifact_name as below.

```
<fieldType class="solr.StrField" name="string" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" />
```

(the above line must be in your schema.xml.)

```
<field name="artifact_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Or You can have another way to it like below.

```
<fieldType name="customFieldType" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>    
</fieldType>

<field name="artifact_name" type="customFieldType" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Comment: first solutin, i am getting no results at all now. i will try your second one

Comment: second solution, gives the same problem. I search for ex. "ios" I get 250 results. When I search "ios 10" i get 500 results

Comment: because it is not just searching artifact name, but also all the other  fields. It works when the search field is one word like ios or android or ubuntu. But two words ios 11, android 10 screws it. cause it starts searching android or 10 not android 10.

Comment: how can i do it "ANDRoId 10" not  android or 10

Comment: did you restart the server after changes...also please provide the sample data...